# Deserialize json into csharp object errors - Could not cast or convert from System.String to ProjectName.Models.CarsModel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'm stuck with a tricky json.
trying to deserialize below web api json into c# object.
Seems like it has no key, only the below value.

**["toyota","bmw","nissan","gmc","mazda","opel","international","honda","ford"]**

Below is my code that is giving me error

`var deserializedObject =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CarsModel>>(result);`

```
public class CarsModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("MyJson")]
    public List<string>? MyJson { get; set; }
}
```

**'Error converting value "toyota" to type 'CarsModel'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 9.'**

**ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to ProjectName.Models.CarsModel.**

Comment: You should first deserialize it to `List<string>` and then use LINQ to create CarsModel List out it.

Comment: Your current json does not match the model, it matches `List<string>`, you need use: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(result)`. If you want to use the model, you need get the json like: `{"MyJson":["toyota","bmw","nissan","gmc","mazda","opel","international","honda","ford"]}`.

Comment: @Chetan I'm still getting the same error. I edited my first post to add the api url link that I am using.

Comment: @Rena I'm still getting the same error. I edited my first post to add the api url link that I am using.

Comment: `var obj = new CarsModel(); obj.MyJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);`

Comment: @Chetan Thank you, your last code solve the issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
public class CarsModel
{
    public CarsModel()
    { 
      MyJson =new List<string>();
    }
    public List<string>? MyJson { get; set; }
}

var deserializedObject =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarsModel>(result);
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's not working. I also edited my first post and added the api url link that I am using.

Comment: Please go here and post your json https://json2csharp.com/. It will suggest how the DTO will be. It is the same as my one.  I have tested and it is working. I have tested it with postman.

Comment: Can you please send me full code you tested. Also I'm using this following api url.  https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories. Will accept your answer and give credit to your post once I test your code.

Comment: @sina_Islam - it seems like https://json2csharp.com/ is producing a wrong result when the input JSON is just an array of strings with no JSON objects at all.  Your `CarsModel` will not successfully bind to a simple JSON array of strings like `["toyota","bmw","nissan","gmc","mazda","opel","international","honda","ford"]`.